# angularfire2 v5 *ngFor itemkey

Tags: angularfire2

When im trying to get the key of an item with angularfire 5 it doesnt seem to work the way it did before the upgrade.

what used to work:

html:

```
<div class="list" *ngFor="let item of items | async" 
(click)="function1( item.$key, ... )
```

ts:

```
 function1( itemkey, ... )
```

and the key of the item would be passed on.

Now it does not produce the same behavior; when I check the value of itemkey its always empty in the called function.

Is it only possible to get the key by snapshot? If so, how do I pass the item itself as a snapshot or something similar to the function so i can get the key within the function ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.  I followed the example at this [github page](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md).

And, to be specific, I created the following service and component.  They work for me.  I understand that in the *ngIf statement in the componnent HTML that I should be using the async pipe ( | async ), but it kept throwing an error so I'll get that sorted separately.  For now, this example works and it's the working version in my code.

SERVICE LISTING HERE (magnet.service.ts):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AngularFireDatabase,
  AngularFireObject,
  AngularFireList
} from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Magnet } from '../models/Magnet';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

@Injectable()
export class MagnetService {
  magnetsRef: AngularFireList<Magnet>;
  magnets: Observable<any>;
  magnet: AngularFireObject<Magnet>;
  userID: string;

  constructor(public af: AngularFireDatabase, 
              private authService: AuthService) 
    { 

    }

  getMagnets(userID: string) {
      this.magnetsRef = this.af.list<Magnet>(userID + '/magnets');
      //use snapshotChanges().map() to store the key
      this.magnets = this.magnetsRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
        return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
      });
    return this.magnets;
  }

  newMagnet(magnet: Magnet) {
    this.magnetsRef.push(magnet);
  }

  getMagnet(userID:string, key: string) {
    this.magnet = this.af.object(userID + '/magnets/' + key);
    console.log("Selected the following magnet: ");
    console.log(this.magnet);
    return this.magnet;
  }

  updateMagnet(key:string, magnet: Magnet) {
    this.magnetsRef.update(key, magnet).then(_ => console.log('update!'));
    return this.magnet;
  }

  deleteMagnet(key: string) {
    this.magnetsRef.remove(key).then(_ => console.log('item deleted!'));
  }
}
```

COMPONENT LISTING HERE (magnet.component.ts)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { MagnetService } from '../../services/magnet.service';
import { Magnet } from '../../models/Magnet';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { AsyncPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-magnets',
  templateUrl: './magnets.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./magnets.component.scss']
})
export class MagnetsComponent implements OnInit {
  items: Observable<any>;
  //this works
  //items: Magnet[];
  user: firebase.User;

  constructor(
    public magnetService: MagnetService,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {


  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      this.user = user;
      this.magnetService.getMagnets(user.uid).subscribe(items => {
        this.items = items;
      })
      })
  }


}
```

COMPONENT HTML HERE (magnets.component.ts)

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row mt-5 pt-5">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <h1>Magnets</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="" class="row">
    <div id="" class="col">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>HeadlineA</th>
            <th>HeadlineB</th>
            <th>SubheadLineA</th>
            <th>SubheadLineB</th>
            <th>LeadA</th>
            <th>LeadB</th>
            <th>Options</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
            <td>{{ item.key }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.HeadlineA }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.HeadlineB }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.SubheadLineA }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.SubheadLineB }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.LeadA }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.LeadA }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.key }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

I hope that helps!